# Jquery to parse Json "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

Where am i going wrong with this

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>title</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.get("http://api.angel.co/1/tags/1654/startups?callback=aaa",
   function(data) {
     $('body').append( "Name: " + data );
   }, "json");

</script>

    </head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.angel.co/1/tags/1654/startups?callback=aaa. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Have you tried using the developer tools in Chrome or Firefox to examine the details of your request and the response?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.angel.co/1/tags/1654/startups?callback=aaa. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

is all i get

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin?rq=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try use jquery `ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"http://api.angel.co/1/tags/1654/startups?callback=aaa",
    type:'GET',
    dataType:'JSONP',
    success: function(data){
        $('body').append( "Name: " + data );
    }
});
```

Comment: Getting response Name: [object Object]

Comment: @Dasa yes, it is json object you can access it like that data.total

Answer (score 2):

*Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin*

You can't hit another domain (*different from what you are on*) using XMLHttpRequest unless you use JSONP

read more about [Same_origin_policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: I understood that adding "?callback=aaa" to the url is jsonp

Answer (score 2):

You must be hosted on some server to run AJAX otherwise it will always say

```
Origin null is not allowed ...
```

Try WAMP/LAMP or use Apache tomcat to run your HTML code on localhost. It will make your domain localhost instead of null and will fix it.

PS: Cross domain problem may still persist depending upon the server you are hitting whether it allows you to get/post data from/to it.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.angel.co/1/tags/1654/startups?callback=?", function(data) {
    $(body).append(data);
});
```

jQuery will replace the ? with a generated function name that calls the inline function.

Answer (score 0):

Include the attribute, "dataType" with the value "JSONP" in yours ajax call. Refer the below example code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.angel.co/1/tags/1654/startups?callback=aaa",
    dataType:'JSONP',
    success: function(data) {
        $('body').append( "Name: " + data.name);
    }
});
```